# Is this an efficient way to use one event for multiple controls?

Tags: c#

I've got a `NumericUpDown` control for each denomination of money and all of the events run the exact same code save for a single line so I'm trying to condense them into 1 event. I was originally going to use a `switch` but you can't switch on a non-value object so I just did an `if` tree. Is there a better way to do this?

```
private void BankInChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var objSender = (NumericUpDown) sender;

        if(objSender == bkI_Ls_Quarters)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setQuarters(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Ls_Quarters.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Rl_Quarters)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setQuarterRolls(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Rl_Quarters.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Ls_Nickels)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setNickels(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Ls_Nickels.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Rl_Nickels)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setNickelRolls(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Rl_Nickels.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Ls_Dimes)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setDimes(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Ls_Dimes.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Rl_Dimes)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setDimeRolls(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Rl_Dimes.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Ls_Pennies)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setPennies(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Ls_Pennies.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Rl_Pennies)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setPennyRolls(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Rl_Pennies.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Ones)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setOnes(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Ones.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Fives)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setFives(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Fives.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Tens)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setTens(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Tens.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Twenties)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setTwenties(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Twenties.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Fifties)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setFifties(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Fifties.Value));
        }
        else if(objSender == bkI_Hundreds)
        {
            currBoat.inBank.setHundreds(Convert.ToInt32(bkI_Hundreds.Value));
        }
        currBoat.updateTotals();
        updateStatDisplay();
    }
```

Comment: Upon loading and just briefly seeing your code, NO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not in switching between senders but the fact that each branch calls a different method on `inBank`. I would suggest creating an enum for the denominations:

```
enum Denomination {
  Quarters,
  QuarterRolls,
  Nickels,
  NickelRolls,
  ...
}
```

and having a single setter in `inBank`:

```
void set(Denomination denomination, int value);
```

Then you can create a dictionary of controls to denominations:

```
IDictionary<NumericUpDown, Denomination> dict = new Dictionary<NumericUpDown, Denomination>();
dict[bkI_Ls_Quarters] = Denomination.Quarters;
dict[bkI_Rl_Quarters] = Denomination.QuarterRolls;
...
```

and your event handler would simply be:

```
private void BankInChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var objSender = (NumericUpDown) sender;
    Denomination denomination = dict[objSender];

    currBoat.inBank.set(denomination, Convert.ToInt32(objSender.Value));
    currBoat.updateTotals();
    updateStatDisplay();
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I'm still pretty new and I've never used a Dictionary before. Will definitely be making use of this.

Comment: I think using collection initializer for your dictionary would make the code even better. Something like `new Dictionary<NumericUpDown, Denomination> { { bkI_Ls_Quarters, Denomination.Quarters }, … };`